# My form doesn't appear in website

Tags: php, oop

I have a question here. Somehow my created registration form doesn't appear on the website. When I am deleting all the `include` files, it shows, but with the files - it does not. Could someone help me to solve this problem? What I'm doing wrong?

Here is my `register.php` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include 'classes/connection.php';
include 'classes/register.php';
$connection = new Connection();
$users = new Users($connection);
$users->insertUserValues();
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form">
        <form method ="post" action="register.php">
            Vardas:<br>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Vardas" required>
            <br>
            Pavardė:<br>
            <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Pavardė" required>
            <br>
            Prisijungimo vardas:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Prisijungimo vardas" required>
            <br>
            Slaptažodis:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Slaptažodis" required>
            <br>
            Patvirtinti slaptažodį:<br>
            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm" placeholder="Slaptažodis" required>
            <br>
            El. pašto adresas: <br>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="El. pašto adresas" required>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Registruotis">
            </form> 
    </div>
</body>
```

The link I'm entering to the registration form is `correct`, I've also tried to go from `index.php`, but it's the same..

Comment: Is the page simply blank when you have the includes? If yes, you'll have errors in your included files. To solve them, turn on PHP error reporting.

Comment: why your are include register.php file as you are calling it on action ?

Comment: Yes, it's blank. Well, thanks, i will try to load included files

Comment: You have fatal PHP errors but you can't see them because you do not have error reporting enabled. Enable them and you'll know *exactly* what is wrong.

Comment: this doesn't seem to do much.

Comment: also the way you instantiate your classes at the top looks sketchy `.$connection = new Connection();
$users = new Users($connection);`

Comment: @Akin what's wrong with that?

Answer (score -1):

Without checking if $_POST['submit'] was set (or any other post var), you immediately call $users->insertUserValues();

What happens inside that? Can we see? I would suggest an if statement to check the form was posted before trying to process non-existent data.

Comment: there is a high chance that it is a syntax error in one of the files included.

Comment: Check inside your insertUserValues() method. Also, look into your error_log and see if you can get any error messages to help with your debugging.